# database is locked exception on drop table

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013, system.data.sqlite

I'm currently facing an issue with database is locked exceptions.

I have a update function like

```
private void UpdateVersion(string version)
{
        string qry = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS version; " +
                     "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS version ( version INTEGER NOT NULL );" +
                     "INSERT INTO version VALUES ("+version+");";
        try
        {
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(qry, this.dbConnection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            // stuff
        }
    }
```

and i always get

```
{"database is locked\r\ndatabase is locked"}
ErrorCode   5
ResultCode  Busy
```

That's a little bit weird because the same query works in SQLite Browser (Like SQLiteStudio or DB Browser for SQLite) without any issues. I figured out that the exception is thrown on the first query part (DROP TABLE).

I'm facing this issue on every DROP TABLE in my code :/.

Does anyone have an idea? :)

Comment: Does it occur if you *just* send the `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS version;` statement?

Comment: yes, i checked it 10 times. Not select qry is infront of the drop qry

Answer (score 2):

This error may appear if you're trying to drop table while a SELECT statement is active on this table.

Answer (score -1):

BEGIN TRAN

USE AdventureWorks

SELECT * FROM Person.Address WITH (UPDLOCK)
WHERE AddressId < 2

SELECT resource_type, request_mode, resource_description
FROM   sys.dm_tran_locks
WHERE  resource_type <> 'DATABASE'

ROLLBACK

Comment: This is SQLite. There is no `USE` and no `WITH (UPDLOCK)`.